# Call google places api from web server

Tags: jersey, weblogic, google-places-api

When I try to call the Google places API using the Jersey REST standalone client it works fine and I am able to retrieve data. But the same code when made part of the web application deployed on weblogic server it throws a 500 internal error. I have tried calling the url directly as well, but that did not work. When the code tries to call the Google Places API it gets 500 internal error as response. I have also set host name verifier as none on weblogic server, that resolves the ssl exception but the 500 internal error is still there.

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing in your weblogic server logs?

Comment: It just says 500 internal error nothing much as error logs other than that. Is there any restriction on calling the Google Places API without enterprise plan from an application server.